# Spark Scala loop join without using foldleft

Tags: scala, apache-spark, left-join

I'm joining a Dataframe `sourceDF`, containing multiple country columns with a DataFrame `countriesDF`.

`sourceDF` :

```
|      id      |     country1     |     country2     |
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1   |         US       |         UK       |
|          2   |         FR       |         SP       |
```

`countriesDF` :

```
|     country      |
|------------------|
|         US       |
|         FR       |
|         UK       |
|         SP       |
```

I need to do the join multiple times, based on the list of column names from `sourceDF`

what I did is this :

```
val list_of_columns: List[String] = List("country1", "country2") // Generic one
val finalDf: DataFrame = list_of_columns.foldLeft(sourceDf){
   case(srcDf, column) =>
       src.join(countriesDF, srcDf(column) === countriesDF(country), "left")
}
```

Now it works fine with a small `sourceDf` and when there is 2 or 3 columns to join on. But in my case the `sourceDf` is 100m rows and I need to do the join on 20 columns.

With all the memory used to create every time a DataFrame, my application is failing with the message :

```
failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 1023410176, max: 1029177344) at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException
```

Is there any better way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the `countriesDF` is a small dataframe, if it's the case then you can broadcast before joining:

```
val list_of_columns: List[String] = List("country1", "country2") // Generic one
val countriesDFbroadcasted = broadcast(countriesDF)
val finalDf: DataFrame = list_of_columns.foldLeft(sourceDf){
   case(srcDf, column) =>
   src.join(countriesDFbroadcasted, srcDf(column) === countriesDF(country), "left")
}
```

This will avoid shuffling data and will result for significant performance improvement.

Comment: I'm on auto broadcast join so it's broadcasted anyway. My issue is that the foldLeft is creating in memory every time a copy of sourceDf and at some point it's blowing.